# How to translate with jsperanto when a key is a sentence (even more sentences)

Tags: javascript, internationalization

We use the jsperanto plugin and some keys in our dictionary are sentences (even more sentences represent one key). Ingenious, because the key separator is the dot.

I'm looking for a simple solution how to pass this key to the translation.

```
{"Approves the version. Optionally, write comment.": "Schválí verzi. Volitelně, napište komentář.",
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "sentence" keys have one parent in the dictionary, so this parent can be used with an option 'flatStructurePrefix'.

```
$.t("bp.Approves this version. Optionally, write version comment.", {"flatStructurePrefix": "bp"});
```